# Repointing Domain from Laravel to Shopify

Tags: laravel, dns, migration, seo, shopify

I'm PMing a project wherein the client's site has been redeveloped/built on Shopify. It is currently on a staging site. Their old site (and one which is still running) is a custom Laravel Ecommerce site which uses Cloudways. We are able to migrate the subscribers across with payment details. We also have an SEO Specialist on call for the migration day. The old site will not be moved to a subdomain but just taken offline.

I am just seeking out some advice regarding who/how to go about changing DNS settings, moving the actual domain from larval to Shopify (as Shopify will now be the new host). What specialist is needed? Can this be done at the click of a button or simply changing DNS settings? What are the risks?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DNS settings is simple enough task for any web developer with even a little bit of experience.
Shopify makes this process even simpler by adding a guide which you can find [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/transferring-domains)

Also, are you using Cloudways as your domain registrar?
As domain registration is different from hosting, you will need to change the DNS settings on your domain registrar configuration.